# Function to translate from English to Morse

Tags: string-manipulation

I am trying to write a function that takes English text and produces the corresponding Morse code. I have a function which works fine when the text consists of lower case letters. But I could not write a proper function which produces the corresponding Morse code when the text has capital letters.

```
ToMorseCode[text_String] := StringJoin[Map[Replace[{"a" -> ".- ", "b" -> "-... ", "c" -> "-.-. ", 
 "d" -> "-.. ", "e" -> ". ", "f" -> "..-. ", "g" -> "--. ", 
 "h" -> ".... ", "i" -> ".. ", "j" -> ".--- ", "k" -> "-.- ", 
 "l" -> ".-.. ", "m" -> "-- ", "n" -> "-. ", "o" -> "--- ", 
 "p" -> ".--. ", "q" -> "--.- ", "r" -> ".-. ", "s" -> "... ", 
 "t" -> "- ", "u" -> "..- ", "v" -> "...- ", "w" -> ".-- ", 
 "x" -> "-..- ", "y" -> "-.-- ", "z" -> "--.. ", " " -> "/ "}], Characters[text]]]
```

Comment: Btw., have you seen [this](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/computational-audio/create-and-decode-a-morse-code-signal.html?product=mathematica)?

Comment: For a long list of rules like yours, you might consider using `Dispatch[]` or `Association[]`.

Comment: @Henrik, yes, that helped me to write my function, but I could not handle writing it with Association[] in a shorter way that will produce Morse code even though the text has capital letters.

Comment: is there a way to make such a program trough the list function, how would that look?

Comment: [Wolfram Challenge](https://challenges.wolfram.com/challenge/write-in-morse-code).

Comment: @J.M.'sdiscontentment Excuse me, I'd like to know how to view the top-ranking reference answers to these challenge program topics.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm somewhat puzzled that OP hasn't written the, to my mind, rather simpler:

```
ToMorseCode[text_String] := StringReplace[
  ToLowerCase[text], {"a" -> ".- ", "b" -> "-... ", "c" -> "-.-. ", 
   "d" -> "-.. ", "e" -> ". ", "f" -> "..-. ", "g" -> "--. ", 
   "h" -> ".... ", "i" -> ".. ", "j" -> ".--- ", "k" -> "-.- ", 
   "l" -> ".-.. ", "m" -> "-- ", "n" -> "-. ", "o" -> "--- ", 
   "p" -> ".--. ", "q" -> "--.- ", "r" -> ".-. ", "s" -> "... ", 
   "t" -> "- ", "u" -> "..- ", "v" -> "...- ", "w" -> ".-- ", 
   "x" -> "-..- ", "y" -> "-.-- ", "z" -> "--.. ", " " -> "/ "}]
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `ToLowerCase[string]` before applying your function.